# gradle composite build execute tasks transitively

Tags: gradle, build

When executing `gradle build` in a composite gradle build only `compileJava` task is executed transitively. Others, like the `test` task are not.

How can I enforce that my tests are also run on build?

I tried:

```
build.dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':build')
```

but that did not work.

> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

here is the gist:

```
// settings
if (file('../myModule').exists()) {
    includeBuild('../myModule')
}

// build1
dependencies {
  compile 'mygroup:MyModule:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Does it works if you let it depend on the `test` task instead of the `build` task? I would also try to create a new task with a different name and set a dependency to the build task there to avoid see if setting such dependencies works at all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you please share your configuration?

Comment: If I add a task build that depends on all included builds tasks `build` to my composite build that includes other builds like `includeBuild('../bla')` that. It works for me. The task looks like ```task build {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':build')
}
``` Could you run `gradle --info build` to check if it gives you a hint about the reason why it does not execute it.

Comment: With your idea I get the error `annot add task 'build' as a task with that name already exists.`

Comment: My root build is not of type java. If I also apply the java plugin to it adding this line to the `build.gradle` file `build.dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':build')`

Comment: You mean for the included or for the including build?

Comment: The including build is not of type java but the included builds are.

Comment: In my case it is 2 multi projects being combined. The root project of the including project does not include scala or java plugin only dependent projects.

Comment: To be able to help you please add the project structure to your question. Also, check the output of `gradle --info build`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174710/discussion-between-mascha-and-georg-heiler).